# g++ error. Understanding line by line

Tags: c++, g++

While compiling one project, I faced one declaration scope error. I understood the error and fixed it, what was not big deal. However, the compiler showed to me a dozen of other messages related with the error that I could not completely understand, and so why this post. The error message is:

```
/home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/src/control.cpp: In static member function ‘static double Control::LineTracking(std::vector<double>, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)’: /home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/src/control.cpp:88:42: error: ‘RAD2DEG’ was not declared in this scope    head = RAD2DEG(atan2(trans[1],trans[0])); 

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ^ 
/home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/src/control.cpp:88:42: note: suggested alternative: 
        In file included from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/utils_defs.h:29:0,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/math/lightweight_geom_data.h:12,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/poses/CPoseOrPoint.h:13,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/poses/CPose.h:12,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/poses/CPose3D.h:12,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/opengl/include/mrpt/opengl/CRenderizable.h:15,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/opengl/include/mrpt/opengl/COpenGLScene.h:12,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/gui/include/mrpt/gui/CDisplayWindow3D.h:13,
                         from /usr/include/mrpt/gui/include/mrpt/gui.h:13,
                         from /home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/include/ransac_project/control.hpp:5,
                         from /home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/src/control.cpp:1: /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/bits.h:83:22: note:   ‘mrpt::utils::RAD2DEG’    inline long double RAD2DEG(const long double x) { return x*180.0/M_PIl; }
                              ^ make[2]: *** [ransac_project/CMakeFiles/ransac_project.dir/src/control.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [ransac_project/CMakeFiles/ransac_project.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2 Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

My interpretation doubts comes from the second block of messages. In it, we have again the file name, the line and column to were the error was identified in the file, and after we have a suggest alternative, which are done by indication of a list of files.

Well, what the compiler wants to mean with these files? The inclusion of any of them in the header of the file with error will solve my declaration problem?

The question may be silly, but I really would like to know exactly what each line of the compiler error messages means. Again, this is not a question on how to solve he declaration problem. It is a question about deeply understanding the error messages!!!

Thanks

Comment: Just look at the first and next to last lines.  * note: suggested alternative*, *from /home/vero/ran/catkin_ws_full/src/ransac_project/src/control.cpp:1: /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/bits.h:83:22: note:   ‘mrpt::utils::RAD2DEG’    inline long double RAD2DEG(const long double x) { return x*180.0/M_PIl; }*

Answer (score 0):

This chain of errors happens when you call a function (RAD2DEG in your case) which the compiler is not able to find (may be a wrong name, wrong signature or missing include). The first line tells you the problem, all the other lines are suggestions of the compiler on how to fix the problem (in this case where you can find something similar to RAD2DEG).

Answer (score 0):

`RAD2DEG()` is an MRPT function that lives in the namespace `mrpt::utils`, so either add a:

`using namespace mrpt::utils;`

or use the full-qualified name: `mrpt::utils::RAD2DEG()`.